# Cannot access internet from kali linux when on NAT network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am a beginner in penetration testing.
I am currently following an [online course](https://www.udemy.com/learn-ethical-hacking-from-scratch/learn/v4/overview), but I am having trouble configuring the network settings.

I have internet connection on kali linux when in NAT, however when I change the settings to NAT network, I no longer am able to access the internet through kali linux.

I have changed the proxy settings to "no proxy", but that didn't change the situation.
What else should I do to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

macOS Sierra: 10.12.6

VirtualBox:  5.2.10 r122088 (Qt5.6.3)

Comment: Why do you want to use “NAT Network”? How did you set up the NAT network in VirtualBox?

Comment: NAT Network will use another subnet. If VirtualBox is on default settings, just reboot kali and try again.

Comment: In the tutorial I am following, the teacher has the settings on NatNetwork  in order to use Kali Linux as an attacking machine towards other vms inside the network.

Comment: I have rebooted and tried again, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

fixed the problem!